# Equation for the intersection of two planes given a parametric equation

Tags: geometry

The problem requires me to give the parametric equation $r = (2,-1,2)+t(3,2,-1)$ in the form of two planes intersecting.

Where do I start? What are the procedure's for converting this sort of thing?

(1st year student so please stay easy on the maths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The answer is not unique. Pick two different point (lets call them $a,b$) on the line of intersection. Then pick two different points ($c,c'$), that are not $\in$ of the line. You can now state two planes. The first uses ($a,b,c$) and the second ($a,b,c'$). Can you complete it from here?

For example let $a=(2,-1,2)$, $b=(5,1,1)$. Now pick $c=(0,0,0)$ and $c'=(2,0,0)$ (veryfy that they are not on the line). The first plane is given by $P_1: \vec{x}=c+(a-c)\mu+(b-c)\lambda$ the second plane is given by $P_2: \vec{x}=c'+(a-c')\mu+(b-c')\lambda$. So any set of two different $c,c'$ points that are not on the line will allow create new planes.

Comment: Thank you for this. I get how you created the two plane's but I don't see how I can link those to the equation and express that parametric equation as the intersection of the two planes?

Comment: Just plug in the values of $a,b,c,c'$ your parameters are $\mu$ and $\lambda$. Or do you want the implicit form of the plane?

Comment: As $a,b$ are on the line and are common in both planes it implies that the line containing these two points is the line of intersection (which is your parametric line equation).